# Convert number to string and add comma to numbers every three digits kdb/q

Tags: formatting, kdb

I am converting integer in kdb/q to string and want comma every three digit in the string. How can I format numbers using a comma separator every three digits using kdb/q?

For example:
Input 298 output: "298"
input 2987 output: "2,987"
input 234523565 output: "234,523,565"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea

```
q){reverse","sv 0N 3#reverse string x}234523565
"234,523,565"
q){reverse","sv 0N 3#reverse string x}1000000000001
"1,000,000,000,001"
```

Comment: I would use `3 cut` instead of `0N 3#`.

Comment: To cover negative input: `{$[x<0; "-";""], reverse","sv 3 cut reverse string abs x}`